# Redis performance on bit arrays

Tags: python, performance, redis, bit-manipulation

As a test, I am implementing a simple bit-manipulation program in both pure Python and Redis. I represent my bit array as a naive Python list (although I am perfectly aware of libraries such as [bitstring](https://github.com/scott-griffiths/bitstring)), and as a string in Redis (since, according to the docs, “it is possible, using special commands, to handle String values like an array of bits”).

Below, initialize a bit array in both Python and Redis (note that the first call to [SETBIT](https://redis.io/commands/setbit) creates the structure), then measure setting 100000 bits to 1, first in Python, then in Redis:

```
import random
import redis
db = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
print("Connected" if db.ping() else "Connection problem!")
db.flushdb()

m = 2 ** 23 # bit array size
n = 10 ** 5 # number of insertions

bit_array = [0] * m
db.setbit("bit_array", m, 0)

random.seed(42)
indexes = [random.randrange(m) for _ in range(n)]

%timeit for i in indexes: bit_array[i] = 1
%timeit for i in indexes: db.setbit("bit_array", i, 1)
```

Result:

```
Connected
5.75 ms ± 849 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.71 s ± 70 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, Redis seems almost 1000 times **slower** than the naive Python structure. Am I doing something wrong?

---

#### Update

Following Žilvinas Jocius' suggestion, I have encapsulated these commands in a pipeline:

```
%%timeit
pipe = db.pipeline()
for i in indexes:
    pipe.setbit("bit_array", i, 1)
pipe.execute()
```

Result:

```
1.07 s ± 16.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, this helps, but Redis is still several orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: Even with your pipeline version I think the main thing you're measuring is the overhead of inter-process communication. The pipeline version has to serialize 100,000 Redis commands, send them across the wire, and deserialize them before any actual bit setting can occur. A better test would be to put it in a Lua script, with the indexes to set in a Redis list, and then test the execution of that script.

Comment: Also, you might want to try initializing the bit array with a `1`. It's possible Redis doesn't bother to allocate the space if you set a `0`, since `GETBIT` returns `0` by default. Can't hurt.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks. I need to stick to the Python API. Concerning your other suggestion, `SETBIT test 1023 0` followed by `STRLEN test` gives 128.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more clear, my suggestion is to use [Lua scripting](https://redis.io/commands/eval) for the *Redis* part of the test, assuming that you want to measure the speed of bit manipulation and not the overhead of sending the commands to Redis.

Comment: Of course, if you're planning to do individual bit manipulations from a Python program like this, then these results make sense - it will be slower to use Redis. Redis will be more memory efficient than this Python implementation, and of course it has the advantage of being available to serve multiple simultaneous clients.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are manipulating db in a synchronous way. After each **setbit** operation you are waiting for response and only then initiating another request. To avoid such case use **[multi](https://redis.io/commands/multi)** / **[pipeline](https://pypi.org/project/redis/)**. Try creating pipeline, set your all requests into one batch and only **then** execute it. It depends which python redis client you are using but it should be something like this:

```
pipe = r.pipeline()

pipe.set('foo', 'bar')
pipe.set('baz')
pipe.execute()
```

Comment: I have edited my question by adding the implementation you suggest. Thanks!